# What do I have to do getting access the port 8787?

Tags: support

So far I have installed RStudio Server. From that [page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started), accessing the server ask to go on the port 8787 with the a browser and `http://<server-ip>:8787`. However, when I try, they gave me the following [page](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=http%3A%2F%2F%3Cserver-ip%3E%3A8787). Where did I make my blunder? What do I have to do getting access the port 8787?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<server-ip>` part of that command means to insert your computer's IP address there. For example, if your computer's IP was `192.168.0.256`, you would go to:

```
http://192.168.0.256:8787
```

If you want to access it from another computer in the same LAN, just go to that same address. If you want to be able to access it from any computer on the internet, you'll have to setup port forwarding on your router's firewall. For more details, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823268/how-do-i-make-my-ubuntu-server-public) answer.

---

If you don't know your IP address, open a terminal, and run `hostname -I` (CaSe sensitive)

Comment: <> is a common notation for wanting to say that whatever is between < and > should be inserted by you, the user.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I didn't realize before.